# where virtual address space is located

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

Didn't able to understand where is virtual address space is present is it in RAM or HARD-DISK?
If it is present in RAM then How it's address space is larger than physical address space?

Comment: It s explained in details on MS pages : [Virtual Address Space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/virtual-address-space)

Answer (score 3):

Virtual addresses,as their name implies, are *virtual*. Their are only manipulated by the processor and do not correspond to actual addresses until they are translated.

Translation is done by the hardware, thanks to tables that are filled by the operating system. These tables indicates for every potential virtual page address to which physical page address it corresponds. So mostly, virtual addresses are mapped to physical (RAM) addresses.

> Didn't able to understand where is virtual address space is present is it in RAM or HARD-DISK? If it is present in RAM then How it's address space is larger than physical address space?

A process always has the same kind of memory structure in terms of virtual addresses. At the lower address end, there are the instructions, global data, and the heap, that are organized in several *sections*. At the upper end, are the program parameters (argv) and the stack. In between there is free space that allows the stack and the heap to grow.
So there are addresse equal to 0 (the first instruction of a program) and to 0xfffffffffffffffff (start of the stack).
Obviously is is far beyond the capacity of most (all?) present RAM.  With 64 bits virtual addresses and a 4GB RAM (32 bits), *at most* one page over 1 billion can be used.
But the mapping mecanism is possible thanks to the page based translation. In the free space between the heap and the stack, most addresses will never be used. In that case, no page table for the translation is created by the OS.
If you generate a random address in a program, the most likely is that it will not correspond to an address mapped by the system to the RAM. If you try any access on this address, the processor will detect that no page exist and will raise an exception that will handled by the system. Most probably the system will stop your program and display an error message like "access violation".

The same mechanism is used to map part of the memory to the disk. To somehow increase  the memory size, the system may swap  to disk part of the physical memory assigned to a process, in order to allocate it to another process. If the first process tries to access it, again an exception will be raised, but the OS will detect that the address corresponds to a memory zone this stored to disk. It will read the disk,  determine a physical address for this page, fill the corresponding page table, restore the memory content and go back to the program that can now perform the memory access.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual Address Space is stored in hard disk. Okay, but where? There are two files that the process uses for this. One of them is the page file, and the other is the swap file.

***But what is the difference between the page file and swap file?***

The **swap file** is used when the memory is completely used up and the process needs more memory. So, the swap is an extended part of the memory. The other utility of the swap file is to switch context between processes. So, for instance, imagine Process A is performing, and Process B is waiting to run. Then, before Process B runs, Process A is removed from the actual context e store in the swap file to wait for its time to run again.

Then we have the **page file**. The page file is used to store the pages that the process is *not using in this moment*. It is used to save memory because this is a limited resource in the PC. Thus, only pages recently used are present in the actual memory. When the CPU tries to access a page that is not present in the memory, the CPU has a exception, which is handled by the Windows, thus restoring the page in memory, updating the page table, and letting the CPU continue performing the process.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual address space is kept in secondary storage (disk). The virtual part of virtual memory means that the operating system maintains an image of the address space in secondary storage. Because an image of the address space is kept in secondary storage, it can be larger than the physical memory.

The second piece of implementing virtual memory is logical address translation that takes place entirely in memory. In the logical address space, memory is subdivided into pages (something like 512bytes to 1MB). Physical memory is subdivided into page frames. The size of a page frame has to match the size of the logical page on most systems.

The operating system maintains a page table for each process. The page table maps pages in the logical address space to physical page frames. An address consists of an index into the page table and an offset into the page used once the page is located.

In most cases there is no mapping of a logical address to a physical address. If you access a page that has no mapping the processor generates a page fault. Once the logical translation fails, the operating system has to do a virtual translation of the page. It looks to see if the page in question is located in secondary storage.

If the page does not exist, the operating system triggers an access violation exception. If the page does exist, the operating system loads the page into a free physical page frame; updates the page to map the page to that page frame, then restarts the process that caused the fault.

A virtual memory implementation has to maintain a copy of each process's virtual address space in secondary storage. It has to be able to translate logical page references into the virtual page stored on disk. It has to be able to copy logical pages in memory between virtual pages on disk.

You can have logical memory translation without virtual memory translation but you cannot have virtual memory translation without logical memory translation.